# What is the equivalent sensor for Intel Realsense

Tags: c++, kinect-v2, realsense

I'm working as an intern.They gave me a code (C++) which is on a camera of Kinect. So they want me to convert it to equivalent code for the camera Intel realsense. So basically I'm getting an error.

```
Cam1(IKinectSensor *t_KinectSensor, WishLog *t_Log);
```

What is the equivalent sensor for Intel Realsense?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a completely different API to work with the realsense camera. The kinect and realsense are not at all compartible. You will need to write it from scratch.